# try and except in while-loop python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, try-except

I am working on a live plot of incoming data. The data comes from a spectrum analyser and sometimes I get faulty data. Faulty in the meaning that there are on some positions letters instead of numbers.

I save the incoming data as a list and then I convert it to a `numpy.array` with

```
trace = np.array(trace, np.float)
```

So when there are letters instead of numbers in one of the entries a `ValueError` is raised and the program is canceled and doesn't plot anymore.

So I was thinking about using `try and except` inside my `while-loop`.

But here the problem arises: The plot doesn't look anymore like it should.

My idea was, that if the data is faulty, the live plot just should not plot the data at all and just skip the drawing. The pieces with wrong data remain white or aren't updated.

Thats how the plot normally should look like:
[image]

I hope you get the idea... With every new piece of data the next sixteenths part of the circle is drawn.

But with `try and except` it looks like this:

[image]

and only the part on the negative y-axes is updated.

Oh and I forgot to mention that the `while-loop` has no breaking condition.

Maybe I have the wrong idea of how `try and except` work. But I hope you can help me.

The code of the `while-loop`

```
while True :
  try: 
        trace = inst.query(':TRACe:DATA? TRACE1').partition(' ')[2][:-2].split(', ')# the first & last 2 entries are cut off, are random numbers

        f = open(timestamp,'a') # open file 
        for value in trace : #write to file 
            f.write(value)
            f.write('\n')


        zeroarray = np.zeros(200) #change the length of zeroarray to gain a bigger circle in the middle
        trace = np.array(trace, np.float)

        indexmax = np.argsort(trace) #gives us the index array of the sorted vector maximum 
        maximum = np.sort(trace) #sorts the array with the values 

        print 'The four maxima are' # prints the four biggest values 
        for i in range(-1,-5,-1):
            if indexmax[i] == 0 :
                frequency = start
            elif indexmax[i] == 600 :
                frequency = stop 
            else :
                frequency = ( indexmax[i] + 1 ) * (start -stop)/601 
            print maximum[i], 'dB at', frequency ,' Hz ' 
        print '\n'

        trace = np.insert(trace,0,zeroarray)
        a = np.linspace(i*np.pi/8+np.pi/16-np.pi/8, i*np.pi/8+np.pi/16, 2)#Angle, circle is divided into 16 pieces
        b = np.linspace(start -scaleplot, stop,801) #points of the frequency + 200  more points to gain the inner circle
        A, B = np.meshgrid(a, trace)


        #actual plotting
        ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

        ctf = ax.contourf(a, b, B, cmap=cm.jet)

        xCooPoint = i*np.pi/8 + np.pi/16 #shows the user the position of the plot
        yCooPoint = stop
        ax.plot(xCooPoint, yCooPoint, 'or', markersize = 15)

        xCooWhitePoint = (i-1) * np.pi/8 + np.pi/16 #this erases the old red points
        yCooWhitePoint = stop
        ax.plot(xCooWhitePoint, yCooWhitePoint, 'ow', markersize = 15)


        plt.draw()
  except ValueError :   
    print('Some data was wrong') 

  i+=1
```

And thanks for the quick help!

Comment: You need to show the code of your loop.

Comment: Yes, please include code; you should always include code you're asking for help with :).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're confused about how `try/except` works. It seems like you expect the plotting function to fill in all the missing gaps.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You said the pieces with faulty data should show white. It looks to me like that big white gap is all faulty data.

Comment: hi barmar, no the data is alright and without try and except it looks totally normal thats why i do not understand the big deal. did i use `try-except` wrong ? 
and the small piece down there is permanently updated and newly drawn.

Comment: I also don't see the problem. What do you mean by "and only the part on the negative y-axes is updated"??

Comment: @RamonCrehuet the whole thing is a live plot. with `try-except` the new data is always plotted into the piece at 270 degrees. 
but it should look like the first picture so sixteenths part beside sixteenths part.. 
it is a plot with **polar-coordinates**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting in the `try/except` clause only what you expect to raise an exception. The code would be more clear and you would be sure that the exception is raised by what you expect to raise it. Something like:

```
try:
    trace = np.array(trace, np.float)
except ValueError:
    print('Some data was wrong') 
    i += 1
    continue
#remaining code...
```

Some more comments:

1. Do you need to open de file at every iteration? Shouldn’t you close it as well?
2. Do you need to create the subplot at every iteration?
3. You are using the `i` variable in `range` and at the end of the `except`. Shouldn't you use different variable names? Are you sure `i` needs only be increased in case of an exception?

Comment: oh my god! your third problem was the problem, thanks.

i wasn't thinking about that.

one more question: what does continue do ?

Comment: and i also tired to change the other things and the plot is now way faster. thanks

Comment: `continue` in a `for` or `while` loop jumps directly to a new iteration (to the start of the block) without executing the remaining part of the block.